# If dark energy disappeared today, what would be the largest gravitationally bound structures in the universe?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, dark-energy, galaxy-clusters

In particular, what would be the largest gravitationally bound structure containing the milky way?

As a bonus, how does this compare to the largest gravitationally bound structures assuming a cosmological constant consistent with current observations?

Comment: Superclusters of galaxies, which are the largest structure currently observable.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask abou dark matter. Dark energy does not affect Milky Way.

Comment: @safesphere no, dark energy is correct.

Comment: https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2016/05/19/how-would-our-universe-be-different-without-dark-energy/